# Grep for a number between a certain range - Checking WAV Quality

Tags: regex, audio, ffmpeg, grep, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to write a regular expression (to be used in conjunction with ffmpeg, which can check that a WAV file is over a certain quality.

The minimum should be:

**Audio Channels:** 2 (Stereo)
**Audio Sample Rate:** 44,100 Hz
**Audio Bitrate:** 1411 Kbps
**Audio Bit Depth:** 16 bit

So I've tried the following commands so far:

- `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "/path/to/file.wav" 2>&1 | egrep 'stereo|2 channels'`

This works fine to get a stero (2 channel) WAV. I'm getting issues with the next part, searching between a range of numbers.

- `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "/path/to/file.wav" 2>&1 | egrep 'stereo|2 channels' | egrep '[41000-196000] Hz'`

Obviously this just searches each number individually, so it's finding results if there's a 4 OR 1 OR 0 OR 0 OR 0 etc...

The bit rate and bit depth just needs to be OVER 1411 and 16 respectively.

Thanks

**EDIT -**
Here's the ffmpeg output for a low quality WAV which should be rejected:

`ffmpeg version git-2012-05-22-27127eb Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 22 2012 12:27:21 with gcc 4.6.1
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      51. 53.100 / 51. 53.100
  libavcodec     54. 21.101 / 54. 21.101
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 75.100 /  2. 75.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[wav @ 0x355b140] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5056000
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from '/path/to/file.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:28.47, bitrate: 512 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 32000 Hz, stereo, u8, 512 kb/s`

Comment: regex is not the good tool to test number ranges (it's however possible). A more clean way is to extract the numbers first and to test them (as numbers) after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded.

I probably should have mentioned this was eventually going to be used in PHP in my original question, sorry! Got caught up on the fact it was doing a basic check breaking out to the command line previously and was trying to follow that route blindly without thinking of other PHP solutions.

In the end, I used [GetID3](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/) to grab  the information we needed and did the checks in PHP. It lists them all nicely in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your egrep:

```
egrep '( 4[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Hz| [5-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Hz| 19[0-6][0-9][0-9][0-9] Hz| 1[0-8][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] Hz)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately number ranges aren't simple and straight forward in regex. This should work for your sample rate but I don't think there is any way of doing a greater than x with regex. You might want to look into awk to see if it is possible there.

```
egrep '(?:4[4-9][0-9]{3}|[5-9][0-9]{4}|1[0-8][0-9]{4}|19[0-5][0-9]{3}|196000) Hz'
```